# Python 3: While loop not returning False

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, while-loop, boolean

I'm making a 3 in a row game for practice using the concepts I have learned in class so far: while loops, booleans, and if-statements.

For some reason, my function doesn't seem to be returning False even though I give an argument in which it should. Instead I get a 'executing command, please wait for result' message, where nothing comes up after that. Initially I thought it was caught in an infinite loop somewhere, but I don't think it should as I gave limits to all my variables and added the +=1 at the end for all of the while loops.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Here is a snippet of my code below:

```
def is_winner(grid):
    x = 0
    y = 0


    while x <=3:
        x +=1
        while y <= 4:  

            if grid[x][y] == grid[x + 1][y] ==grid[x + 2][y]:
                y += 1

                return True
    while x <= 3: 
        x +=1
        while y <= 3:
            if grid[x][y] == grid[x + 1][y - 1] == grid[x + 2][y - 2]:
                y +=1

                return True

    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only ever increment `y` if the `if` statements are `True`. If they never are, you entered into an infinite loop:

```
while x <=3:
    while y <= 4:  
        x +=1
        if grid[x][y] == grid[x + 1][y] ==grid[x + 2][y]]:
            y += 1
```

Your inner `while` loop never completes, so your outer `while` loop is never tested.

Change this to:

```
while x <=3 and y <= 4:  
    x +=1
    if grid[x][y] == grid[x + 1][y] ==grid[x + 2][y]]:
        y += 1
```

Comment: Oh ho! You're my hero! Thank you :)

Comment: Quick question. To use [x][y] like (x, y) coordinates, do I need to import math or something? I keep getting string index out of range.

Comment: If your `grid` list contains *other* lists, then using `grid[x]` refers to an index in the outer list, and the `[y]` part then applies to that returned value, also a list. If you get string index errors, then either `grid` is a string itself or it is a list where at least one of its values is a string.